# 3rd column in 3 column grid not positioning properly

Tags: html, css

I am an absolute beginner to web development, I am trying to replicate this [desktop view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vT5px.png) and this [tablet view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnqNr.png). I have tried several ways but the 3rd column wont stay on same line as the rest and the whole view just looks a mess.

The html markup:

```
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Our Menu</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1> our menu</h1>
      <div class="row">
        <div class=" design col-wd-4 col-md-6" >
          <div> <h4 id="chicken1">chicken</h4> </div> 
          <p> just some rubbish content i really dont know what i was thinking. this layout is a mess</p>
        </div>

        <div class=" design col-wd-4 col-md-6">
          <div> <h4 id="chicken2">chicken</h4> </div> 
          <p> just some rubish content i really dont know what i was thinking. this layout is a mess</p>
        </div>

        <div class=" design col-wd-4 col-md-12">
          <div> <h4 id="chicken3">chicken</h4> </div> 
          <p> just some rubbish content i really dont know what i was thinking. this layout is a mess</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    position: relative;
}

.container {
    width: 90%;
}

#margin {
    margin: 10px;
}

div h4 {
    position: absolute;
    top: -20;
    right: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}

.design {
    padding: 0 5px;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: darkgrey;
    text-align: justify;
    color: black
}

div p {
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 29px 0px;
}

#chicken1 {
    background-color: darkred;
    color: white;
}

#chicken2 {
    background-color: white;
}

#chicken3 {
    background-color: coral;
}

.row {
    width: 100%;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/* Media Queries */

/* Mobile */
@media (min-width:992px) {  
    .col-wd-4{
        float: left;
    }

    .col-wd-1 { width:8.33333%; }
    .col-wd-2 { width:16.66667%; }
    .col-wd-3 { width:25%; }
    .col-wd-4 { width:33.33333%; }
    .col-wd-5 { width:41.66667%; }
    .col-wd-6 { width:50%; }
    .col-wd-7 { width:58.33333%; }
    .col-wd-8 { width:66.66667%; }
    .col-wd-9 { width:75%; }
    .col-wd-10 { width:83.33333%; }
    .col-wd-11 { width:91.66667%; }
    .col-wd-12 { width:100%; }
}

/* Tab */
@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width: 991px)  {
    .col-md-1 { width:8.33333%; } 
    .col-md-2 { width:16.66667%; }
    .col-md-3 { width:25%; }
    .col-md-4 { width:33.33333%; }
    .col-md-5 { width:41.66667%; }
    .col-md-6 { width:50%; }
    .col-md-7 { width:58.33333%; }
    .col-md-8 { width:66.66667%; }
    .col-md-9 { width:75%; }
    .col-md-10 { width:83.33333%; }
    .col-md-11 { width:91.66667%; }
    .col-md-12 { width:100%; }
}

/* Tab */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .col-sm-1 { width:8.33333%; }
    .col-sm-2 { width:16.66667%; }
    .col-sm-3 { width:25%; }
    .col-sm-4 { width:33.33333%; }
    .col-sm-5 { width:41.66667%; }
    .col-sm-6 { width:50%; }
    .col-sm-7 { width:58.33333%; }
    .col-sm-8 { width:66.66667%; }
    .col-sm-9 { width:75%; }
    .col-sm-10 { width:83.33333%; }
    .col-sm-11 { width:91.66667%; }
    .col-sm-12 { width:100%; }
}
```

Attached is the jsfiddle link with my code
https://jsfiddle.net/q60mbr5h/

Please any help would be highly welcome, I am so confused. Thank you

Comment: thank you for the edit on the html structure but there are no changes to the layout in browser.

Comment: This is because the widths you calculate in your media-queries. col-wd-4 is 33,3%, but you also have margins of 10px (both sides).

Comment: ok, so in essence I cant have the desired layout with width of 33.3%?

Comment: You need to take into account all of your size settings. If you have 3 columns of each 33.3%, but they also have a margin of 10px, and are in a container of 90% width, your content overflows to the next line.

Comment: i am making use of the 12 grid layout if I make the the width 25% which is the percentage before 33.3% the layout in browser wont spread out as nicely like the example picture attached

Comment: If you want to use a 12 grid layout, you're better off using bootstrap or another framework, rather than trying to create all the media-queries yourself. You need to take more into account than just dividing the width by 3. A workaround for your case would be to reduce the percentages to take into account the margins. For instance change col-wd-4 to 30%.